# SQL Query - Compare fields in different rows of same table

Tags: sql, ssms

I have the below table which is a result of UNION operation and working on SSMS

| ID | Name | Address | Group_ID | City |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | John | 14710 BRUCE DOWNS BOULEVARD | NULL | TAMPA |
| 101 | John | 14710 BRUCE DOWNS BOULEVARD | MEDICAL | TAMPA |
| 101 | John | 10000 BRUCE DOWNS BOULEVARD | MEDICAL | TAMPA |

In which IDs are same but each row is different than row above, for example, row 1 - Group_ID is "NULL" for row 2 it changed to "MEDICAL".
I want to display name of the column in each row which has difference when compared to the row above.
Output is expecting like this,

| ID | Name | Address | Group_ID | City | Column Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | John | 14710 BRUCE DOWNS BOULEVARD | NULL | TAMPA |  |
| 101 | John | 14710 BRUCE DOWNS BOULEVARD | MEDICAL | TAMPA | Group_ID |
| 101 | John | 10000 BRUCE DOWNS BOULEVARD | MEDICAL | TAMPA | Address |

Anyone please suggest some SQL queries to solve the problem.

Thanks in Advance
Meenu

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your results appear to depend on the ordering of the rows.  Without a column specifying the ordering, this is meaningless.

Comment: You can use `window functions` for this task however as above, you need to have some way of determining the ordering of rows.

Comment: Order of the row will be always remains as the same given above.

Comment: @Meenu: Then what `ORDER BY` clause are you using to guarantee that order?

Comment: I also have some other columns in my table which include some 'DATE' column, So I'm using order by 'DATE'.

Comment: The only thing I need to know is Can we have any queries to compare two adjacent rows by column by column? When comparing row1 and row2, I want to display which column has change. Can you please suggest any methods for that?

Comment: What if there are two or more differences?

Comment: Then i think i have to place the column names as comma seperated values.

Comment: What version of SqlServer are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server 2016

Answer (score 1):

Use `LAG` to get the previous row's data. Use `CONCAT_WS` to conveniently list the diff columns. Use `ROW_NUMBER` to detect the first row in order not to report differences for it (`LAG(column)` is null for the not existing row before the first one).

```
select 
  id, name, address, group_id, city,
  case when row_number() over (order by ...) > 1 then
    concat_ws
    (
      ', ',
      case when coalesce(address, 'NULL') <> coalesce(lag(address) over (order by ...), 'NULL') then 'address' end,
      case when coalesce(group_id, 'NULL') <> coalesce(lag(group_id) over (order by ...), 'NULL') then 'group_id' end,
      case when coalesce(city, 'NULL') <> coalesce(lag(city) over (order by ...), 'NULL') then 'city' end
    )
  end as columns
from mytable
order by ...;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a2f53246f5af0c2def674b01b3d0e290